# Mongoose update value with value from other field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Am I able to update a value in `findOneAndUpdate`, with a other value from this document?

My data structure looks like

```js
User: {
  email: "test@mail.com",
  test: {
    token: "someFancyToken",
    email: "other-email@test.com"
  }
}
```

How I wish to change the data

```js
await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    'test.token': token,
  },
  {
    email: test.email,
    test: null
  },
)
```

**Output**

```js
User: {
  email: "other-email@test.com",
  test: null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use the aggregation pipeline for update operations so you can do something like this:

```
await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 'test.token': token },
  [{ $set: { email: "$test.email", test: null } }]
)
```